# Is there a single word for the quality of doing good works for others without any selfishness?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, uncountable-nouns

Can anyone give the exact single word for the feeling/quality of doing good works for others without having any selfishness?

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective or a noun?  You ask for "the feeling/quality" and then tag "adjective".  Single word requests require an example sentence.

Answer (score 3):

"selflessness"

> > Having, exhibiting, or motivated by no concern for oneself;
> >     unselfish
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/selfless)

Quote:

> Twenty-five million veterans are living among us today.
>   These men and women selflessly set aside their civilian lives to put
>   on the uniform and serve us.
>   - Steve Buyer
>   [Link](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/steve_buyer_338492)

Also "altruism"

> 1. Unselfish concern for the welfare of others; selflessness.
>      [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/altruistic)

Quote:

> “Every man must decide whether he will walk in the light of creative
>   altruism or in the darkness of destructive selfishness.” ― Martin
>   Luther King Jr
>   [Link](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/martin_luther_king_jr_132188)

There is also "philanthropy", but I think this word is less suitable, as not all philanthropists might act out of complete selflessness.

Answer (score 1):

Doing good without a selfish motivation is called '**altruism**'.

> Disinterested or selfless concern for the well-being of others, esp. as a principle of action. Opposed to selfishness, egoism, or (in early use) egotism.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/5857?redirectedFrom=altruism#eid)

> The gift of giving: How does altruism improve teens' lives?

[Medical News - 25 Dec 2017](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/320432.php)

> New research finds that altruism - and social media - can help corporations cultivate trust with consumers

[PhysOrg - 20 Feb 2018](https://phys.org/news/2018-02-corporations-benefit-altruism-crisis.html)